# UIPickerView tap gesture not working swift 1.2

Tags: swift, picker

I have a working uipickerview with the following code

```
class DateTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var colors: [String] = ["red","green","blue"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myPicker = UIPickerView()

        myPicker.dataSource = self
        myPicker.delegate = self

        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        var myGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pickerTapped:")

        myPicker.addGestureRecognizer(myGR)
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return colors.count
        }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
            return colors[row] as! String
        }

    func pickerTapped(sender : UIView) {
            println("Tap Gesture recognized")
        }

}
```

unfortunately nothing happens when i tap the picker view items, can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Why are you trying to capture the tap events on the picker view? If you are trying to execute some code when an item in the picker is selected you should probably look at implementing the `didSelectRow` function in the [pickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:) instead.

Comment: I want to implement "tap to select" feature, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The picker view already handles *'tap to select'* behaviour, allowing you to implement selection logic in the `DidSelectRow` method specified in the PickerView Delegate Protocol.

Get rid of the gesture recognizer and replace your `pickerTapped` function with the following code instead:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    println("\(colors[row]) was selected")
}
```

The reason that your tap gesture recogniser isn't triggering is because the Picker View is already handling the tap gesture to manage selection, and will notify it's delegate when a selection is made. You don't need to handle this selection manually.

Comment: If you're going to do iOS development, you'll really need to understand the [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) pattern. The answer above is simply one example of it in action.